# How to transfer a table from Acces to Excel using VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in Access that I need to transfer to an Excel on a regular basis. I want to create a VBA script in my excel sheet so I can just pull that table in as soon as I run the VBA script. I recorded the following VBA script by doing the steps manual and it pulls the table correctly. However, when I try to run the VBA script from Excel, it gives me an "runtime error 1004: Application-defined or object defined error" and highlights the following line at the bottom of the VBA script:
.ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database8"

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
 Sub TestMacro()

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=C:\Users\ariahm\Desktop\AA-Quarterly TSO Changes - December 2015.mdb;DefaultDir=C:\Users\ariahm\Desk" _
        ), Array("top;DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;")), _
        Destination:=Range("$C$5")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT Test_AA.RPT_DT, Test_AA.INDX_SYM_TX, Test_AA.INDX_SRC_CD, Test_AA.ISSUE_ID, Test_AA.ISSUE_SYM_ID, Test_AA.ORG_NM, Test_AA.`Current Index Shares`, Test_AA.`Current TSO`, Test_AA.`Current Date`, " _
        , _
        "Test_AA.`Current Source`, Test_AA.`New Index Shares`, Test_AA.`New TSO`, Test_AA.`New Date`, Test_AA.`New Source`, Test_AA.`TSO Change`, Test_AA.`TSO Pct Change`, Test_AA.`IS Change`, Test_AA.`IS Pct " _
        , _
        "Change`, Test_AA.`All New Index Shares`, Test_AA.`All New TSO`, Test_AA.`All New Date`, Test_AA.`All New Source`, Test_AA.Global, Test_AA.MIC_CD, Test_AA.BRS_ID, Test_AA.`Current Float Factor`, Test_A" _
        , _
        "A.`Current Float Date`, Test_AA.`Current Float Shares`, Test_AA.`New Float Factor`, Test_AA.`New Float Date`, Test_AA.`New Float Shares`, Test_AA.`All New Float`, Test_AA.`All New Float Date`, Test_AA" _
        , _
        ".`All New Float Shares`, Test_AA.Reason, Test_AA.`Entered By - Initials`, Test_AA.`Date Entered`, Test_AA.`Prelim Current Float Shares`, Test_AA.`Prelim New Float Shares`, Test_AA.SEDOL_ID" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM Test_" _
        , "AA Test_AA")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database8"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: why not write the query directly in your Access database and set up a data connection and just write `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` or `ThisWorkbook.Connections("myConn").Refresh` in your macro. Much simpler that way. But to answer your question, since you already have a Table Named `Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database8` (from the first time you set it up) Excel is throwing an error because it can't have two objects with the same name. If you really want to do it this way, you'll have to delete your table before re-importing it.

Comment: Tried your first suggestion and it worked well. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@ScottHoltzman wrote in a comment:

> Why not write the query directly in your Access database and set up a data connection and just write `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` or `ThisWorkbook.Connections("myConn").Refresh` in your macro. Much simpler that way. But to answer your question, since you already have a Table Named `Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database8` (from the first time you set it up) Excel is throwing an error because it can't have two objects with the same name. If you really want to do it this way, you'll have to delete your table before re-importing it.

Comment: ([Converted a comment to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))